# Using DispatchGroup() in Swift 3 to perform a task?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

With Swift 3, using GCD has changed to `DispatchGroup()`, and I'm trying to learn to use it in my code.

Currently I have a function in another class that attempts to download a file and output its speed. I like to have that function finish first because I assign its speed to a `var` that I will be using in the first class to perform other tasks that is dependent upon that `var`.

It goes something like this:

Second class:

```
func checkSpeed()
{
    // call other functions and perform task to download file from link

    // print out speed of download

    nMbps = speedOfDownload
}
```

First Class:

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
let check: SecondClass = SecondClass()

myGroup.enter()

check.checkSpeed()

myGroup.leave()

myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

    print("Finished all requests.")

    print("speed = \(check.nMbps)")
})
```

The problem is `Finish all requests` gets output first, thus returning `nil` for `speed`, then afterwards `checkSpeed` finishes and outputs the correct download speed.

I believe I'm doing this wrong, but I'm not sure?

How can I ensure that `speed` obtains the correct value after the completion of `checkSpeed` in my first class?

The details of `checkSpeed` is exactly the same as `connectedToNetwork` from GitHub: [connectedness.swift](https://github.com/rldaulton/connectedness/blob/master/connectedness.swift)

Comment: It depends on how your `checkSpeed()` is invoking the download task. You need to show some more details of the method.

Comment: If you are talking about **one** file you need an asynchronous completion handler rather than a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With hint provided in the comment and solution found here: [from @vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251503/2373410), since I am only performing one task, I used a async completion handler:

Second Class:

```
func checkSpeed(completion: @escaping () -> ())
{
    // call other functions and perform task to download file from link

    // print out speed of download

    nMbps = speedOfDownload
    completion()

}
```

First Class:

```
let check: SecondClass = SecondClass()

check.checkSpeed {
print("speed = \(check.nMbps)")

}
```

Now `checkSpeed` will complete first and `speed` is assigned the appropriate value.

Answer (score 11):

You need to call `DispatchGroup.leave()` when the entered task has completed. So, in your code, `myGroup.leave()` needs be placed at the end of the completion handler inside your `checkSpeed()` method.

You may need to modify your code like this:

```
func checkSpeed(in myGroup: DispatchGroup) {
    //...
    ...downLoadTask... {...its completion handler... in
        //...

        // print out speed of download

        nMbps = speedOfDownload

        myGroup.leave() //<- This needs to be placed at the end of the completion handler
    }
    //You should not place any code after invoking asynchronous task.
}
```

And use it as:

```
myGroup.enter()

check.checkSpeed(in: myGroup)

myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

    print("Finished all requests.")

    print("speed = \(check.nMbps)")
})
```

But, as noted in vadian's comment or Pangu's answer, you usually do not use `DispatchGroup` for a single asynchronous task.

---

**ADDITION**

I need to say, I strongly recommend *completion handler pattern* shown in Pangu's answer. It's a more general way to handle asynchronous tasks.

If you have modified your `checkSpeed()` to `checkSpeed(completion:)` as suggested, you can easily experiment `DispatchGroup` like this:

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
let check: SecondClass = SecondClass()
let anotherTask: ThirdClass = ThirdClass()

myGroup.enter() //for `checkSpeed`
myGroup.enter() //for `doAnotherAsync`

check.checkSpeed {
    myGroup.leave()
}
anotherTask.doAnotherAsync {
    myGroup.leave()
}

myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {

    print("Finished all requests.")

    print("speed = \(check.nMbps)")
}
```

Comment: OOPer: apologize GCD has already confused me from the beginning, but without going into too much details, `DispatchGroup` group is mainly used for..?...groups of asynchronous tasks?

Comment: _`DispatchGroup` is mainly used for groups of asynchronous tasks?_ Right. `DispatchGroup` is intended to use with multiple asynchronous tasks, to expect to be notified when **all** the tasks in the group has finished. When all the tasks entered in the group have called `DispatchGroup.leave()`, the closure specified with `notify(queue:execute:)` is invoked.